# How to fix this regex validation method?

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I am a new C# developer and I am using `Regex` class for my first time.

As I am developing a validation class for my simple project, I am using Regex to develop a number of methods that will take care of user(s) inputs validation. I am struggling right now with developing a method that will validate the number of characters entered by the users against the limited number of characters that varies from one text field to another.

```
public void ValidateLength(string input, int count)
{
    string regFormat = @"[a-zA-Z]{" + count.ToString() + "}";
    string message = "";

    Regex reg = new Regex(regFormat);
    foreach (var regexMatch in reg.Matches(input))
    {
        message = regexMatch + "The maximum length is" + count;
    }
}
```

Then, since I have the following TextBox in ASP.NET:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I am trying to use the validation method with those two TextBoxes, However, it doesn't work and I don't why:

```
Validate validate = new validate();
if(txtBox.Text.toString() != "")
{
   if(validate.ValidateLength(txtBox.Text.toString(), 20)
   {
      //Do this stuff
   }
}
```

Would you kindly help me in fixing/modifying this validation method in order to make it working with any `TextBox` and and specified length by the user?

Comment: for the length you can use the maxlength property in the textbox

Comment: ValidateLength doesn't return anything it's prototyped as void so you can't use it in the 'if' as you've shown.  You also need to be careful using regex's for arbitrary input.  You should always use the overload with the timespan to guard against Catastrophic Backtracking (see http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: So you have to just return a boolean value saying whether given text is below the max length isn't it?

Comment: What I want is to use this method in such a way that I can check that the string is not exceeding the specified length. If it exceeds, return false with mentioning the length, if not proceeds.

Comment: is there any way to use it inside if statement and return the length if the text is longer than the specified length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to return the length back, You're the one who is passing it inside. Youknow it right?

```
public bool ValidateLength(string input, int count)
{
    string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z]{0," + count.ToString() + "}$";
    return Regex.IsMatch(input,regFormat);
}
```

You're almost there your pattern was `[a-zA-Z]{" + count.ToString() + "}` this matches only when there is exactly `n` number of elements found not less than `n`.

So here is what I updated `{0,n}` matches zero to `n` number of elements in input string. `^` and `$` ensures the start and end of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and clear explanation. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, that you want to verify the input count. Change the function to this one. Try the following :

```
 public void ValidateLength(string input, int count)
    {
        string message;
        string regFormat = @"[a-zA-Z]{" + count.ToString() + "}";

        Regex reg = new Regex(regFormat);
        Match m = reg.Match(input);
        if (! m.Success)
        {
            message = "The maximum length is" + count;
        }


    }
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. However, I am looking to resolve this issue:
`Validator validator = new Validator();
        if (TextBox1.Text.ToString() != "")
        {
            if(validator.ValidateLength(TextBox1.Text.ToString(), 10)){
/// Do the following stuff
}
else
{
//show the user an error message telling him about the required length}}`
**Could you please tell me how to do this correctly as I can't convert type void to bool? And if I converted and I will not be able to show the maximum length.**